# EJS template renders out nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am basically learning Node.js and EJS and i have this code :

index.js :

```
var express = require('express');


var app = express(); // createApplications();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

app.get('/profile/:name', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.params.name);
    res.render("profile", {username : req.params.name});
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(err){
    if(err)
        throw err;
    console.log("Listening at IP:PORT " + process.env.IP + ':' + process.env.PORT)
});
```

views/profile.ejs :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body { 
               background : skyblue;   
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h5>Profile of <?= username ?> </h5>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i go to profile/someone .. it says Profile of .. and blank. Im confused on why it doesnt render out the username passed via the object `res.render("profile", {username : req.params.name});` . and that console.log test to `req.params.name` is good.

Comment: i think its just as simple as your template is wrong, i think the brakets should be `<%= username %>`

i cant test at the moment so only commenting

Comment: @olly_uk .. wow how did i do that? ... :/ . Ok thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using '?' as delimiter without configuring it.

```
ejs.delimiter = '?';  // add this line
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

`<body>
        <h5>Profile of <?= username ?> </h5>
    </body>
</html>`

to

`<body>
        <h5>Profile of <%= username %> </h5>
    </body>
</html>`

And it should display your variable properly. 
You used the wrong syntax!